# Хранение АТД в файлах

Tags: база-данных, структуры

Изучаю алгоритмы и АТД (абстрактные типы данных). И вдруг меня осенило: а как же АТД хранятся на HDD? Например, связный список:

```
struct Node {
    Item item;
    Node *next;
}
```

ведь указатель он только в памяти указатель. Честно сказать, не смог правильно сформулировать вопрос и, соответственно, найти литературу по данному вопросу.  Подскажите. По базам данных в литературе этот вопрос, вроде, не освещается. Как деревья, списки и тп структуры отображаются в файлах. Где, в какой книге подробно освещается данный вопрос?

Comment: Вам нужна техническая документация на каждую отдельную БД. Способы реализации везде различны. В оракле например записи адресуются rowid который включает в себя номер файла данных, нормер блока в файле и номер записи в блоке. С индексами примерно то же самое указатель на блок и адрес/смещение внутри блока. Я как то делал хранилище данных с отражением на память mmap по фиксированным адресам, было удобно, обычные указатели продолжали работать после перезапуска приложения

Comment: различны то различны, но есть же некий набор приемов. не может же быть в каждой СУБД свои технологии. как АТД общие же для разных БД. алгоритмы общие - например MSD, LSD или QSort общие же... да, у кого-то InsertSort потом подъедает за QSort и тд. Хотите сказать что нет литературы обощающей по данному вопросу. ВУЗовский курс то есть на эту тему? как называется?

Comment: Наверняка есть и литература и курсы. начните с поиска на тему ISAM (который был еще на ЕС ЭВМ уже в 60х годах и используется по сей день) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM  Хотя это конкретно не про ваши АТД.

Comment: Но подход может быть только один адрес в ОЗУ во время работы при записи на диск должен быть преобразован в некий адрес на диске. когда то это были адреса типа цилиндр-головка-сектор, потом пришли на смену файлы. А в файле так же смещение от начала либо номер (при фиксированном размере записи) ну и укзатель на сам файл, если нужен, хоть абстрактным номером, хоть путем (хотя путь хранить дорого). ничего другого то не придумаешь

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.